# java.io.InputStream will not throw IOException when Wifi connectivity is lost

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I am running into an issue with some code in my Android application which downloads a file from a URL, here is a code snippet:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
final byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
InputStream stream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();

try {
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Read from steam, Bytes Read: " + bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //Recover from lost WIFI connection.
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

My application relies on `InputStream.read()` to throw an `IOException` if WiFi connectivity is lost. As stated in the [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) this method should throw an `IOException` *"if the input stream has been closed, or if some other I/O error occurs"*. In Android M, this occurs immediately and my code can process and recover from the exception. In Android N, this exception is not thrown which causes my app to simply hang in the `read()` method, it never breaks out of it. Has anyone else run into this problem and worked around it in such a way that doesn't break backwards compatibility? Is this a new Android N bug?

Comment: It might be tied to the switch to the OpenJDK. Is there a way of consistently reproducing it (e.g., you hang if the device gets toggled into airplane mode)?

Comment: Maybe your device switches to mobile data and tries to keep up the connection. Have you set a connection timeout for your connection?

Comment: I have been reproducing it by switching off wifi from the quick settings menu during the download without a SIM card (to take that out of the equation). This reproduces it every time.

Comment: I sincerely apologize, it turns out I was using a device that was tampered with. Testing on another device and everything is working fine. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 2):

Reading from a socket can block forever if the connection goes down. You need to use a read timeout.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reinventing the wheel and find yourself figuring out this and some other common scenarios, I would use a high library such as **Volley**

> see: [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Volley offers you in a very straight forward way interesting things as:

- timeout control
- Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff
- control of several kind of errors
- cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
- Debugging and tracing tools.
- etc

**Sending a request is as easy as something like this** (from the docs )

```
  final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**Setting a timeout/retry policy is as easy as:**

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
```

where the parameters are:

- Timeout: Specifies Socket Timeout in millis per every retry attempt.
- Number Of Retries: Number of times retry is attempted.
- Back Off Multiplier:  A multiplier which is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.

**Regarding error handling**

As you see, you are passing  an error listener `new Response.ErrorListener()`  to the request. When there is an error, Volley invokes the onErrorResponse callback `public void onErrorResponse` method passing an instance of the VolleyError object when there is an error while performing the request.

The following is the list of exceptions in Volley, taken from this post [here](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

- AuthFailureError — If you are trying to do Http Basic authentication then this error is most likely to come.
- NetworkError — Socket disconnection, server down, DNS issues might result in this error.
- NoConnectionError — Similar to NetworkError, but fires when device does not have internet connection, your error handling logic can club
- NetworkError and NoConnectionError together and treat them similarly.
- ParseError — While using JsonObjectRequest or JsonArrayRequest if the received JSON is malformed then this exception will be generated. If you get this error then it is a problem that should be fixed instead of being handled.
- ServerError — The server responded with an error, most likely with 4xx or 5xx HTTP status codes.
- TimeoutError — Socket timeout, either server is too busy to handle the request or there is some network latency issue. By default Volley times out the request after 2.5 seconds, use a RetryPolicy if you are consistently getting this error.

So you can do things like

```
  if ((error instanceof NetworkError) || (error instanceof NoConnectionError)) {

     //then it was a network error

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @EJP says "Reading from a socket can block forever if the connection goes down", just add this line to your code , and also catch java.net.SocketTimeoutException :

```
int bytesRead = 0;
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        InputStream stream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        try {
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Read from steam, Bytes Read: " + bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            //Recover from lost WIFI connection.
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
```